# My Batch apex is covering only 50% test coverage can anyone help me to make it 100% coverage

Tags: batch

```
global class FCSTCopyFinancialDataBat implements 
      Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

Public string Query='SELECT Name, Account__c, FCST_Actual_Amount__c, FCST_Backlog_Amount__c, '+
    'FCST_Prior_Year_Amount__c, FCST_Recurrent_Amount__c, FCST_Target_Amount__c, Fiscal_Period__c,'+
    ' Fiscal_Year__c, Opportunity__c, Planning_Measure__c, Planning_Version__c, Quarter__c, User__c '+
    ' FROM FCST_Plan_Models__c where Planning_Version__c =:previousversion';

     global string previousversion;
     global string nextversion;
     global FCSTCopyFinancialDataBat(String PV,String NV){
     // Query='SELECT Name, Account__c, FCST_Actual_Amount__c, FCST_Backlog_Amount__c, FCST_Prior_Year_Amount__c, FCST_Recurrent_Amount__c, FCST_Target_Amount__c, Fiscal_Period__c, Fiscal_Year__c, Opportunity__c, Planning_Measure__c, Planning_Version__c, Quarter__c, User__c FROM FCST_Plan_Models__c';
     PreviousVersion=Pv;
     NextVersion=NV;
  }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext Bc,list<FCST_Plan_Models__c> scope){
    List<FCST_Plan_Models__c> newPlanModels= new List<FCST_Plan_Models__c>();
      for(FCST_Plan_Models__c m: scope){
          FCST_Plan_Models__c palnobj  = m.clone(false, false, false, false);
            palnobj.Planning_Version__c=nextversion;
          newPlanModels.add(palnobj);
        }
         if(newPlanModels.size()>0){ 
            system.debug('##3:'+newPlanModels);
            //insert newPlanModels;
     }    

  }


global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}

}
```

**
The Test class code is as below
**

```
@isTest (SeeALLData=false)
public class Test_FCSTCopyFinancialDataBat {
 static testMethod void testMethod1() {

 Date startDate = System.today();
 Date endDate = startDate.addDays(30);
    List<Account> acc =new List<Account>();
    Account accs = new Account();
    accs.Name = 'Testing1';
    accs.type ='Prospect';
    insert accs;
    system.assertEquals('Testing1',accs.Name);


    FCST_Fiscal_Year_List__c fiscalList=new FCST_Fiscal_Year_List__c();
    fiscalList.Name ='2018';
    fiscalList.StartDate__c = system.today();
    fiscalList.EndDate__c = System.today().addDays(5);
    insert fiscalList;   

    Date fstartDate = Date.newInstance(system.today().Year(),1,01);
    Date fendDate = Date.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(),12,31);

    FCST_Fiscal_Year_List__c fyp = new FCST_Fiscal_Year_List__c(Name = fstartDate.Year()+'',StartDate__c = fstartDate,EndDate__c = fendDate);

    insert fyp;

    map<Integer,String> mapMonthString  = new map<Integer,String>();
    mapMonthString.put(1,'January');
    mapMonthString.put(2,'February');
    mapMonthString.put(3,'March');
    mapMonthString.put(4,'April');
    mapMonthString.put(5,'May');
    mapMonthString.put(6,'June');
    mapMonthString.put(7,'July');
    mapMonthString.put(8,'August');
    mapMonthString.put(9,'September');
    mapMonthString.put(10,'October');
    mapMonthString.put(11,'November');
    mapMonthString.put(12,'December');
    map<Integer,String> mapMonthStringshort  = new map<Integer,String>();     mapMonthStringshort.put(1,'Jan');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(2,'Feb');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(3,'Mar');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(4,'Apr');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(5,'May');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(6,'Jun');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(7,'Jul');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(8,'Aug');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(9,'Sep');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(10,'Oct');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(11,'Nov');
    mapMonthStringshort.put(12,'Dec');
    map<Integer,String> mapQuater  = new map<Integer,String>();
    mapQuater.put(1,'Q1');
    mapQuater.put(2,'Q1');
    mapQuater.put(3,'Q1');
    mapQuater.put(4,'Q2');
    mapQuater.put(5,'Q2');
    mapQuater.put(6,'Q2');
    mapQuater.put(7,'Q3');
    mapQuater.put(8,'Q3');
    mapQuater.put(9,'Q3');
    mapQuater.put(10,'Q4');
    mapQuater.put(11,'Q4');
    mapQuater.put(12,'Q4');
    string strmultiselect;


    FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c fisYearModel=new 
    FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c();
    fisYearModel.Name ='FY2018P01';
    insert fisYearModel;     

    List<FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c> fcstli=new list<FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c>();

    for(integer i=0;i<12;i++){

        FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c objfym=new FCST_Fiscal_Year_Model__c();

        integer val=i+1;
        objfym.Month_Number__c=val;
        objfym.Start_Date__c= Date.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(),1,val);
        objfym.End_Date__c= startDate.addDays(30);
        objfym.FCST_Fiscal_Year_List__c = fyp.id;
        objfym.name='FY'+Date.Today().Year()+'P0'+val;
        objfym.Fiscal_Quarter__c = mapQuater.get(val); 
        objfym.Fiscal_Year__c = system.Today().Year()+'';  
        objfym.Long_Label__c =  mapMonthString.get(val);
        objfym.Period_Name__c = mapMonthString.get(val);
        objfym.Period_Number__c =val;
        objfym.Record_Source__c = 'Installation';
        objfym.Short_Label__c = mapMonthStringshort.get(val);           
        objfym.Update_planning_model__c =false;
        strmultiselect += objfym.Fiscal_Year__c+'-'+mapQuater.get(val)+',';

        fcstli.add(objfym);

    }

    insert  fcstli;        

FCST_Planning_Version__c nv=  new FCST_Planning_Version__c(

        name= 'Open(Admin)',
       Is_this_a_Budget_Planning_Version__c = false,
                Version_Status__c= 'Open(Admin)',
                Planning_Version_Fiscal_Year__c =Date.Today().Year()+'',

                Fiscal_Year_Planning__c=fyp.id,
                Fiscal_Period__c=fcstli[0].id,
                MonthName__c = mapMonthString.get(0)

           );

    insert nv;

  FCST_Planning_Version__c pv=  new FCST_Planning_Version__c(
        name= 'Closed',
       Is_this_a_Budget_Planning_Version__c = false,
                Version_Status__c= 'Closed',

                Planning_Version_Fiscal_Year__c =Date.Today().Year()+'',

                Fiscal_Year_Planning__c=fyp.id,
                Fiscal_Period__c=fcstli[0].id,
                MonthName__c = mapMonthString.get(0)

           );
  insert pv;

    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<4;i++){
            Account acc1 = new Account(Name='Test Account'+i);
            accList.add(acc1);

        if(accList!=null && accList.size()>0)
         upsert accList;
         acc1=accList[0];
}

    List<FCST_Plan_Models__c> lstModels = new  List<FCST_Plan_Models__c>();
           for(Integer j=0;j<12;j++){
              FCST_Plan_Models__c newPlanModels = new FCST_Plan_Models__c();
               newPlanModels.Account__c=accList[0].id;
               newPlanModels.FCST_Actual_Amount__c=500+j;
               newPlanModels.FCST_Backlog_Amount__c=700+j;
               newPlanModels.FCST_Recurrent_Amount__c=900+j;
               newPlanModels.FCST_Target_Amount__c=600+j;
               newPlanModels.FCST_Product_Family__c='1.2 Netw Conn & Serv';
               newPlanModels.Fiscal_Year__c=fyp.id;
               newPlanModels.Planning_Version__c=nv.Id;


               lstModels.add(newPlanModels);
           }
            insert lstModels;

    Test.startTest();
    FCSTCopyFinancialDataBat Obj = new FCSTCopyFinancialDataBat('Pv.Id','NV.Id');
    Database.executebatch(Obj,200);

    Test.stopTest();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the part of the test not being covered is the `execute` method and I believe it is because your query won't return any records. In your query String, you've used the variable name `previousversion` but you've put in inside the String literal. If you want the value of `previousversion` you'll need to put the value in the string like this:

```
 where Planning_Version__c = \'' + previousversion + '\'';
```

This will put the value of previousversion in the query surrounded by single quotes. **Please also note** that you will need to escape any single quotes in `previousversion` to avoid [injection vulnerabilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).

Now In your test class you pass the **String** `'Pv.id'` again this is not the value of The Pv objects id field/member but the literal string 'Pv.id' if you want the actual value of `Pv.id` and `Nv.id` then remove the single quotes. 
I would suggest making use of `System.debug()` or breakpoints in order to see what variables values are at different points.